# blob displays on extractvalue in mysql workbench 6.2

Tags: mysql, sql, blob, mysql-workbench, extract-value

I am using MySQL Workbench (6.2.3) and I am using ExtractValue() to grab data from an XML string.  Using code similar to:

```
Select
 Table2.user_id,
 ExtractValue(TableName, '//CustomerSource//LeadID') as LeadID.
 ExtractValue(TableName, '//CustomerData//City') as City
From
 Schema.Tablename,
 Schema2.Table2
Where
 Tablename.TransactionID = Table2.TransactionID
;
```

When the output is delivered, all values created using ExtractValue are viewed as BLOB.  When viewing these BLOBs in the viewer, the data is correctly displayed.
I have already tried treating BINARY/VARBINARY values as non-binary strings.

Does anyone know a workaround, fix, or reason that these values are displayed as BLOB?

Also, this code works on older MySQL Workbench installations just fine.  I would attempt to install an earlier version, but this is for my team at work and it would be easier to just direct them to the most updated install of MySQL Workbench.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are really asking, but assume you don't want to show the extracted values as BLOBs. Solution: try casting the result to a varchar.

Comment: In Version 6.0.9 the code returns the appropriate character values.  For some reason, version 6.2 returns BLOB.  The code is an attempt at extracting data from the BLOB, and to get a mini-blob in return is a little disappointing.
-EDIT:  Back space redirected web page
Thank you for the response.  I will try and cast the data later.